# Structured Streaming Kafka Source Offset Storage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, offset, spark-structured-streaming

I am using the Structured Streaming source for Kafka [(Integration guide)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), which as stated does not commit any offset.

One of my goals is to monitor it (check if its lagging behind etc). Even though it does not commit the offsets it handles them by querying kafka from time to time and checking which is the next one to process. According to the documentation the offsets are written to HDFS so in case of failure it can be recovered, but the question is:

Where are they being stored?
Is there any way of monitoring the kafka consumption (from outside of the program; so a kafka cli or similar, the offset coming with each record does not suit the use case) of a spark streaing (structured) if it does not commit the offsets?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structured Streaming for kafka saves offsets to HDFS below structures.

Example checkpointLocation setting is below.

```
.writeStream.
.....
  option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkPoint")
.....
```

In that case, Structured Streaming for kafka saves below path

```
/tmp/checkPoint/offsets/$'batchid'
```

Saved file contains below format.

```
v1
{"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":$'timestamp',"conf":{"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
{"Topic1WithPartiton1":{"0":$'OffsetforTopic1ForPartition0'},"Topic2WithPartiton2":{"1":$'OffsetforTopic2ForPartition1',"0":$'OffsetforTopic2ForPartition1'}}
```

For example.

```
v1
{"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":1505718000115,"conf":{"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
{"Topic1WithPartiton1":{"0":21482917},"Topic2WithPartiton2":{"1":103557997,"0":103547910}}
```

So, I think for monitoring offset lag, it needs to develop custom tools what has below functions.

- Read from offsets from HDFS.
- Write offset to Kafka __offset topic.

That way, already existing offset lag monitoring tool can monitor Structured Streaming for kafka's offset lag.

Answer (score 0):

***Method 1:***
If you have configured `checkpointLocation` (HDFS/S3 etc) go to the path and you will find two directories `offsets` and `commits`. Offsets hold the current offsets while commits have last committed offsets. You can navigate to commits directory and open the latest modified file in which you can find the last committed offsets. While the latest file in offsets directory holds info of consumed offsets.

***Method 2:***
You can also monitor the same with the following configurations:

```
class CustomStreamingQueryListener extends StreamingQueryListener with AppLogging {

  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
    logDebug(s"Started query with id : ${event.id}," +
      s" name: ${event.name},runId : ${event.runId}")
  }

  override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    val progress = event.progress
    logDebug(s"Streaming query made progress: ${progress.prettyJson}")
  }

  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
    logDebug(s"Stream exited due to exception : ${event.exception},id : ${event.id}, " +
      s"runId: ${event.runId}")
  }

}
```

and add it to your streams config.

```
spark.streams.addListener(new CustomStreamingQueryListener())
```

Answer (score -1):

Few things to note:

**Monitoring**: Ready made monitoring can be found in Streaming tab of Spark job. You can see what is the current batch that is getting processed and how many are in queue to check the lag.

**Check max and min offset for a topic** : You have the cli to check these. Can use below from the server where the kafka broker is present:

```
kafka-run-class \
kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
--broker-list your_broker1:port,your_broker2:port,your_broker3:port \
--topic your_topic \
--time -2
```

More detailed info can be obtained, if you integrate with Grafana

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However:

- For monitoring In the already made monitoring for Spark Structured Streaming there is no such thing as "batches" or "records" with a queue as there is in Spark Streaming. Or at least I do not see it in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However: - For the kafka tool the problem with this is that that tool does not support SSL. There is a PR for it, but not merge (or release yet). Plus this would give me the offset of the topic, but not how much my consumer is lagging, for that thes is another tool in kafka but the problem is that Spark Structured Streaming does not commit the offsets (the option 'auto.commit.offset' is not supported) therefore the offsets are ONLY handled withing spark in some folder I cannot manage to find.

Comment: Yes you were right that spark will not save offsets. We are just saving them to a mysql database. Or you can write to a file. However this is not in structured streaming though. You should be able to get the offset atleast when the program is running and then save it.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I wanted to know if by any chance I could avoid that. According to the documentation, Sparks uses a WAL to save the offsets to HDFS (I guess only with checkpointing enabled) but I didnt manage to see where.

Thanks!

Comment: If we are using dstreams, then WAL are not used. Its only for old implementation

Comment: Im using structured streaming, not normal Spark Streaming. Therefore Dataframes. Nor RDD, nor DStreams (If im not wrong).

The slides on it are: https://es.slideshare.net/julesdamji/a-deep-dive-into-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark From the commiters. As you can see in slide 39 they mention the WAL, so there is one in this case. I just cannot find it.